# Summing an infinite series $\frac{7}{8} - \frac{49}{64} + \frac{343}{512} - \frac{2401}{4096} +\cdots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\frac{7}{8} - \frac{49}{64} + \frac{343}{512} - \frac{2401}{4096} +\cdots$$

So I am not sure how to replicate this into summation notation but I have several ways of doing it and I have no idea which one is the right one because clearly some (all) don't work and only specific versions of the replication do work.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt7}{\sqrt8}^{(2(n+1))}$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty -1^n \cdot \frac{7}{8}^{n+1}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty -1^{n+1} \cdot \frac{7}{8}^{n}$$

And several others, I would jsut be wasting my time because I am sure I am doing these all so horribly wrong as to embarrass myself.

Anyways trying to use the form $\dfrac{1}{1-r}$ doesn't give the correct answer on any of these.

Comment: You shouldn't write -1^{n+1} if you mean (-1)^{n+1}.  Note that $-5^2=-25$ but $(-5)^2=25$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n$th term of $7,49=7^2,343=7^3,2401=7^4\cdots$ is $7^n$

and the $n$th term of $8,64=8^2,512=8^3,4096=8^4\cdots$ is $8^n$

So using the [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) of Infinite Geometric Series, the sum $$\sum_{1\le r<\infty}\left(\frac78\right)^r(-1)^{r-1}=\sum_{0\le r<\infty}\frac78\left(-\frac78\right)^r=\frac{\frac78}{1-\left(-\frac78\right)}=...$$

Comment: You used the formula wrong, if you change the index from 0 to 1 you have to use the formula $\frac{cr^M}{1-r}$

Comment: @PaulthePirate, rectified. Please check

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{7}{8} - \frac{49}{64} + \frac{343}{512} - \frac{2401}{4096} +\cdots=\frac{7}{8}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{7}{8}\right)^n=\frac{7}{8}\frac{1}{1-(-7/8)}$$